# Nextjs only go to page on button click not by typing it directly into the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js, server-side-rendering

In Next.js with SSR:
I need to implement something so that when a user directly types in a certain link into the browser like: 'www.website.com/helloworld' the user will automatically be redirected to the home page. I only want the user to be able to get to that page after they click a certain button (specifically after filling in a form and clicking submit). Can someone point me into the right direction on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You also can redirect user on SSR, from your protected page get `appContext` from page's `getInitialProps` and use its `appContext.ctx.res.writeHead` method.

```
appContext.ctx.res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/' }).end()
```